# Marking modules using "yarn upgrade-interactively"

Tags: yarnpkg

In running `yarn upgrade-interactively`, how does one actually mark individual modules for an upgrade?

The "Enter" and "X" and various other keys don't check-mark the modules in the list and neither does clicking them with a mouse!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest version of Yarn, instructions are printed on the command line: The space bar selects individual modules and "a" selects all modules for update.